# Why is BITWISE & used in ERC 1155 implementation

Tags: erc-1155

I am trying to understand why BITWISE AND (&) operator used instead of LOGICAL AND (&&) operator in ERC 1155 implementation.

Link -
https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155/blob/master/contracts/ERC1155MixedFungible.sol

Just for more clarity, I am also stating the code here.

If someone can explain with help of an example, that would be great.

```
function isNonFungible(uint256 _id) public pure returns(bool) {
    return _id & TYPE_NF_BIT == TYPE_NF_BIT;
}
function isFungible(uint256 _id) public pure returns(bool) {
    return _id & TYPE_NF_BIT == 0;
}
function getNonFungibleIndex(uint256 _id) public pure returns(uint256) {
    return _id & NF_INDEX_MASK;
}
function getNonFungibleBaseType(uint256 _id) public pure returns(uint256) {
    return _id & TYPE_MASK;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do so because the values manipulated `TYPE_NF_BIT`, `NF_INDEX_MASK` and `TYPE_MASK` are used as bit flags or bit masks.

That way they can encode several pieces of information in a single `uint256 _id`.